# Disabling all radios from the system level; AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, android-wifi, android-bluetooth, android-gps

I'm trying to disable radios for things like WiFi, BT, GPS, and any other telemetry from the system level on AOSP. Specifically, I'm trying to do it in a quick-settings tile or an item on the shutdown menu, but I'm not quite sure how to embark on this task. 
I can make APKs and quick-settings tiles, but I don't know how to access radios on a low level, setting them to *off*, not *dormant*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airplane mode does the same. You can look into Airplane mode implementation and can do similar implementation for your requirement.

Once Airplane mode is changed, [ConnectivityService](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#5491) broadcasts `ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED` action to all the radio classes (WiFi, Bluetooth, Network, etc.). Based on this action device's radio is turned off.